# Shapefile point coordinates to lonlat

Tags: shapefile, coordinate-system, c++, utm

I'm currently trying to parse a shapefile (http://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) with c++. 
While I have no problems parsing all the data I need, there is a problem with the coordinates. I got a description file for the data, which states that the used projection is "ETRS89 (Ellipsoid: GRS80), UTM (Zone 33)".

I need all points to be in lon/lat format. I spent the whole day googling around to find a solution for this problem, but there doesn't seem to be one.

data example:

```
33354891.477852, 6060028.67074774
        ^               ^
       X (E)           Y (N)
```

Comment: Download QGIS 2.0 load the shapefile and set the CRS (projection) to WGS84 (latlng) and export will give you point shapefile with latitude and longitude. http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Comment: there must be a programmatical way. i don't want to load each shapefile manually...

Comment: you still need to reproject the data. C++ reproject shapefiles http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139335/which-c-library-for-esri-shapefiles-to-choose

Comment: @Mapperz that link is for reading shapefiles, not reprojecting data.

Comment: also, i don't want to reproject the whole shapefile. it would be enough to get a formula to calculate the lon/lat from these coordinates

Comment: @Mapperz how do i reproject them? i tried changin the layer's CRS...but it doesn't do anything...when i export it, it's still the same format...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ projection library proj

https://trac.osgeo.org/proj/

We've used DLLImport to write calls into it from C# code for [MapDotNet](http://www.mapdotnet.com) and [MapsJS](http://mapsjs.com), works great!

You'll need to go to http://spatialreference.org/ to get proj4 strings for your source and destination projections (WGS 84 is a good choice for lat/lon)

Call pj_init_plus(initParameters) with each of your strings (returns an int*)

Then call

pj_transform(projFrom, projTo, arraySize, 1, xArray, yArray, null);

where arrays hold your coordinates (the null is for a z array which I assume you don't need).

Degrees will come out in radians, you'll need to convert to 360 degree format.  Returns 0 on success, or a proj error code.

Comment: hmm...isn't there just a formula to convert a point? i don't really want to use big libraries...

Comment: Yes, but it is different for every family of projections.

Comment: Here's the Wikipedia for UTM to degrees http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#From_UTM_coordinates_.28E.2C_N.2C_Z.2C_Hemi.29_to_latitude.2C_longitude_.28.CF.86.2C_.CE.BB.29  It is not a simple formula.

Comment: Hmmm...some code i could steal, without using a whole library? i only need that one conversion...

Comment: It's an open-source library.  You can dig through the source.

Comment: i guess i'll have no choice but using the whole library...thanks

Comment: well, i can't get it to work...have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19197791/projapi-gis-library-heap-overflow

Comment: Try using the precompiled binaries.  It's hard for me to directly address your question because I pInvoke from C#.  We marshall as LPStr, which means single-byte null-terminated strings, so another possible problem is that you are compiled for wide strings.  But the error you cite looks like it expected a heap pointer and got a stack pointer, to fix that you may need to allocate a pointer and copy the string to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you've got X/Y values in ETRS89/UTM 33 but you want ETRS89 lat/longs instead, then you will need to use the Transverse Mercator formula. However, the ellipsoid formula is ... rather complicated.

[image: tm_projections]

If you've got a little geodetic knowledge, then it is entirely possible to calculate lat/longs from the X/Ys yourself, but I would strongly suggest reading the [EPSG Guidance on Conversions and Transformations](http://www.epsg.org/guides/docs/G7-2.pdf) (p.45 starts the Transverse Mercator) for a full description of all the terms involved.